# Trying to get my Game Loop right

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do my very first simple game.

My question is: why is my game loop not working? If you see the code, I tried to put all the game code inside an if. The idea is: "if game over is false, execute the game, else (when my humanHungerBar reaches 0) the game is over".

Can you help me here? Thanks a lot

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    }

    #screen {
    position: relative;
    left: 480px;
    top: 30px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    }

    #myCash {
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 7px;
    left: 5px;
    border: 5px solid lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: green;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    #humanHunger {
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 280px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }

    #humanHungerContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    }

    #humanHungerBar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 76%;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: green;
    }

    #moneyMaker {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    top: -850px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    background-image: url("moneyMakerBackground.png");
    }

    #jobInstructions {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    top: 20px;
    left: 22px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #workingHours {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    top: 90px;
    left: 22px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
    }

    #workCounter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    top: 250px;
    left: 22px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #clickingArea {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    top: 170px;
    left: 22px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    filter: saturate(100%);
    }

    #clickingArea:hover {
    filter: saturate(190%);
    }

    #dollar {
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
    top: 5px;
    }

    #nakedHuman {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 120px;
    }

    #clothesScreen {
    position:relative;
    top: -400px;
    left: 900px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    }

    #lumberShirt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 165px;
    left: 120px;
    display:none;
    }

    #coffeeStainedTShirt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 165px;
    left: 120px;
    display:none;
    }

    #regularJeans {
    position: absolute;
    top: 328px;
    left: 145px;
    display:none;
    }

    #lumberShirtMiniContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    }

    #coffeeStainedTShirtMiniContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    }

    #regularJeansMiniContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    left: 20px;
    }

    #burgerMiniContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    left: 10px;
    }

    #lumberShirtPrice {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    }

    #buyButtonLumber {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 3px solid lightgreen;
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    }

    #buyButtonCoffee {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 3px solid lightgreen;
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    }

    #buyButtonRegularJeans {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 3px solid lightgreen;
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    }

    #buyButtonBurger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;
    border: 3px solid lightgreen;
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="screen">
            <img id="nakedHuman" src="nakedHuman2.png" width="139.46" height="450">
            <img id="lumberShirt" src="lumberShirt.png" width="139.46" height="158.51">
            <img id="coffeeStainedTShirt" src="coffeeStainedTShirt.png" width="139.46" height="158.51">
            <img id="regularJeans" src="regularJeans.png" width="89" height="152.72">
            <div id="myCash"></div>
            <div id="humanHunger">
                <div id="humanHungerContainer">
                    <div id="humanHungerBar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="clothesScreen">
            <div id="lumberShirtMiniContainer">
                <img id="lumberShirtMini" src="lumberShirt.png" width="70.38" height="80">
                <div id="lumberShirtPrice"></div>
                <div id="buyButtonLumber">Buy</div>
            </div>
            <div id="coffeeStainedTShirtMiniContainer">
                <img id="coffeeStainedTShirtMini" src="coffeeStainedTShirt.png" width="70.38" height="80">
                <div id="buyButtonCoffee">Buy</div>
            </div>
            <div id="regularJeansMiniContainer">
                <img id="regularJeansMini" src="regularJeans.png" width="46.62" height="80">
                <div id="buyButtonRegularJeans">Buy</div>
            </div>
            <div id="burgerMiniContainer">
                <img id="burger" src="burger.png" width="94.11" height="80">
                <div id="buyButtonBurger">Buy</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="moneyMaker">
            <div id="jobInstructions">You work on a click factory, so get to clickin'!!</div>
            <div id="workingHours"></div>
            <div id="clickingArea"><img src="dollar.png" id="dollar" width="82.55" height="42"></div>
            <div id="workCounter"></div>
        </div>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var gameOver = false;
        if (!gameOver) {
        var lumberShirtPrice = document.getElementById("lumberShirtPrice");
        lumberShirtPrice.innerHTML = 7;


        var myCash = document.getElementById("myCash");
        myCash.innerHTML = 45;

        var buyButtonLumber = document.getElementById("buyButtonLumber");
        buyButtonLumber.addEventListener("click", substractItemPriceFromMyCash);
        var negateFX = new Audio('negate1.wav');

        function substractItemPriceFromMyCash() {
            var a = parseInt(lumberShirtPrice.innerHTML);
            var b = parseInt(myCash.innerHTML);
            if (a > b) {
                negateFX.play();
            }
            else {
                myCash.innerHTML -= lumberShirtPrice.innerHTML;
                console.log("you bought the lumber shirt");
            }
        }

        var workingHoursScreen = document.getElementById("workingHours");
        workingHoursScreen.innerHTML = 0;
        var workCounter = document.getElementById("workCounter");
        workCounter.innerHTML = 0;
        var allowedToWork = false;
        var workingHoursChronometer = setInterval(incrementWorkingHoursChronometer, 1000);
        function incrementWorkingHoursChronometer () {
            var a = parseInt(workingHoursScreen.innerHTML);
            if(a < 10) {
                workingHoursScreen.innerHTML++;
            }
            else if (a == 10) {
                workingHoursScreen.innerHTML = 0;
                workCounter.innerHTML++;    
            } 
            var b = parseInt(workCounter.innerHTML);
            if (b == 4) {
            workCounter.innerHTML = 0;
            }
            if (b % 2 == 0) {
            allowedToWork = true;
            }
            else if (b % 2 == 1) {
            allowedToWork = false;
            }
        }



        var coinFX = new Audio('coin1.wav');
        var clickingAreaBox = document.getElementById("clickingArea");
        clickingAreaBox.addEventListener("click", giveMeMoney);

        function giveMeMoney() {
            if(allowedToWork) {
                myCash.innerHTML++;
                coinFX.play();
            }
            else {
                negateFX.play();
            }
        }

        var humanHungerBar = document.getElementById("humanHungerBar");
        var barWidth = 76; 
        humanHungerBar.style.width = barWidth + '%';
        var humanHungerBarDecrement = setInterval (decreaseHumanHungerBar, 700);
        function decreaseHumanHungerBar () {
            if (barWidth > 0) {
                humanHungerBar.style.width = barWidth + '%';
                barWidth--; 
            }
        }

        var buyButtonBurger = document.getElementById("buyButtonBurger");
        var burgerPrice = 15;
        buyButtonBurger.addEventListener("click", buyBurgerRestoreLifeAndDecreaseMoney);
        function buyBurgerRestoreLifeAndDecreaseMoney() {
            var a = parseInt(myCash.innerHTML);
            if (a >= burgerPrice){
                if(barWidth < 92) {
                    barWidth += 10;
                    myCash.innerHTML -=burgerPrice;
                }
                else if (barWidth == 1) {
                gameOver = true;
                console.log("bar is 1");
                }
                else {
                    negateFX.play();
                }   
            }
            else {
            negateFX.play();
            }
        }
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("screen").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your code with your question please

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: You don't have a game loop. You have that if statement inside the onload handler which only ever gets called once.

Comment: but can you elaborate on how to get it right?

Comment: The reason you're getting downvoted is because people like to see the code in the body of the question, rather than having to go to your site and view the source. The easier you make it for people to help you the better.

Comment: The closest thing to a 'game loop' you have here is your setInterval function that is getting called every second. You probably want to put the if statement in there.

Answer (score 1):

So you have written a script that executes one time. It goes from beginning to end, and then stops. So what you want to do is write a script that repeats over and over until the game ends. So here's a super brief example of how you might do that in javascript:

```
while (!gameOver) {
  // do game code
}
```

**BUT WAIT!!!**

So the code inside that while loop will keep on happening over and over until the gameOver variable is true. But if you try to use that code, your game will probably freeze! Why? Because the browser is executing the code inside the while loop as fast as it possibly can. But if you'd like your game to run at a certain frame-per-second rate, you probably want to use a javascript timeout. So try something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // do game code
}, 1000/60);
```

That is the **absolutely bare minimum** that you'll need for a technical "game loop". However, this is not really the recommended approach for starting to create a browser-based game. Try doing some research and checking out things like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Introduction) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWzzRkxrTMA&ab_channel=JeroenBeekman).